# Fastest way to insert into link table

Tags: java, sql, database, insert, derby

I want to `INSERT` the ID's from two tables into a link table to resolve a many to many relationship.

What is the fastest, most efficient way to `INSERT` without making a complex `JOIN` from two tables? I need it to only insert if it will not create duplicates too.

I have read that `MERGE` might be effective but looks like you can only use 1 source table.

I have two tables joined by a link table. The schema is below:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
field1 VARCHAR(40))

CREATE TABLE table2
(id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
field1 VARCHAR(100),
field2 INT,
field3 VARCHAR(40))

CREATE TABLE linkTable
(id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
field1 INT REFERENCES table1(id),
field2 INT REFERENCES table2(id))
```

I have an index on table1.field1 and table2.field1.

Comment: If you place a unique index on the link table, it will refuse the duplicates with an exception that you can catch and discard.

Comment: Hi @Bryan. I tried that approach but when performing batch inserts, if any exception is raised it forgets the rest of the records to insert.

Answer (score 0):

probably you looking for union and distinct:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tabc (id)
SELECT id 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM taba 
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tabb ) x
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO tabc (id)
SELECT id 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM taba 
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tabb ) x
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tabc WHERE id = x.id)
```

If tables taba and tabb have many rows (and only part of it will be inserted), then maybe more optimal will be insert rows filtered separately:

```
INSERT INTO tabc (id)
SELECT id 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM taba a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tabc WHERE id = a.id)
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tabb b
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tabc WHERE id = b.id)) x
```

if you always insert rows into tabc after insert into taba or tabb, then maybe you build triggers after insert on taba and tabb?

In Apache Derby you can use MERGE, but need two commands:

```
MERGE INTO tabc c
USING taba a
ON a.id = c.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id) VALUES (a.id);

MERGE INTO tabc c
USING tabb b
ON b.id = c.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id) VALUES (b.id);
```

Comment: Isnt `DISTINCT` expensive for `SELECT`? And Im looking to insert incrementally rather than once the other two are populated.

Comment: if you have indexes on id then it will be fast, if id is unique in taba and tabb, then you don't need it. Witch DBMS you use?

Comment: I'm using Apache Derby. INSERT IGNORE would solve all my issues but unfortunately it's not available for Derby! My problem is that when I INSERT into the link table even with an index, the Insert time grows with the size of the table.

Comment: Post definition of tables with indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Adam! I have updated my post as requested.

Comment: What you try to do? Can you post sample of data and expected result?